# Mongoose: Documents aren't updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm finding documents by `_id` in a loop and updating a boolean in each document:

```
db.items.findById(key, function(error, item) {

  item.flags.cake = false;

  item.update(function(error, zzz) {
    if(error) return next(error);
    console.log('output ',zzz);
  });    
});
```

But the documents will not update. The mongoose schema for `item`:

```
flags: {
    cake:Boolean
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `item.save`?

Comment: Where does `next` come from? Also, the `update` is asynchronous operation, and using a loops means that your `key` is set to the last element of the loop. Therefore I suppose only the last element will be updated? Try creating a function to be called on each cycle of the loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`save()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)** method instead which makes use of a callback that will receive three parameters you can use:
1) `err` if an error occurred
2) `item` which is the saved item
3) `numAffected` will be 1 when the document was successfully persisted to MongoDB, otherwise 0.

```
Items.findById(key, function(error, item) {    
    item.flags.cake = false;

    item.save(function (err, item, numAffected) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log('output ', item);
    });    
});
```

As an extra measure of flow control, save will return a Promise.

```
item.save().then(function(item) {
    console.log('output ', item);
});
```